# How to Set A connection String before Building a c# Application so that it can be run on Client Computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, connection-string, database-connectivity

I Just made an application in C# using Visual Studio and create databases in SQL Server 2012. Now I have to Build the application and install in Client PC. The Problem is that Connection String is Set on my PC, How can I manage all the steps for installing the whole System (Data Base + Visual Studio application) in Client Computer.

Comment: is database in local server?

Comment: No, Currently database is in my machine.
I have to deliver the The database + Build exe file.